# Fix diffrent text amount to web browser content

Tags: c#, css, webbrowser-control

I have a `web browser` in my `win form`
I'm filling it's content with some text for each time(text size in each loop almost the same size).

my web browser size is `fixed`
i want to aromatically fix my content text to browser content
(for example if my content text size is more than the web browser content with some algorithm fix it to content and do not show scroll)
exactly some algorithm that fix `Css` for each content size to web browser size

is it possible?(may be some thing like change text size for best fix or ...)

Answer (score 0):

all you really need to do it wrap your text inside some DIV tag, and this will auto encapsulate the text in your DIV to fit the window.

I'm assuming you do not want the horizontal scroll bar, is that correct? Because you haven't specified, I'm just guessing. If it is the vertical scroll bar you do not want, then let me know.

Otherwise, if you're text input is being placed in many different areas, and you really need more global or generalized control over this, you can alter the WIDTH attribute in your BODY tag to ensure it is exactly, or a few pixels smaller than the width of your WebBrowser control.

So if your WB control width is 600, you would place this in your BODY tag of the HTML page you have loaded (i'm assuming you have access to the HTML page, if not, once again, let me know).

`<BODY WIDTH="590">`

Let me know how you go, and if I've totally missed or misunderstood your question, please let me know and add the details necessary so that we can understand what you need.

Cheers.

Comment: Exactly i don't want to use vertical and horizontal scroll,i have access my HTML code and i specify width.i have some text for each page(like a book)every text amount (text size in each page almost the same size).i just want to find a way show each page (for example in WB with width 500 and height 400)with no scroll and all the text put in my WB area.thanks.

Comment: @irsog there is a javascript property where you can specify Scroll Bars preference, could be named NoScrollBars or something similar, you should be able to set this in javascript, and i think the modern WB Control exposes this as well, so you can do it with the WB control, also, perhaps more importantly, you should be able to specify it in the BODY tag as well. Also, i know for sure that you can specify it in an iframe or any frame for that matter, just like this: IFRAME SCROLLING="auto|yes|no", in your case, a NO would mean scrolling is off even if it is needed (for both height and width).